# How to avoid TLE in this bingo program?

Tags: c

I'm writing a bingo game program in C, which was getting "Time Limit 
Exceeded" when the online judge gave me huge bingo boards like 256*256 board with 1 player or 150*150 board with 6 player. How can I optimize my code so as to avoid TLE from occurring? (sry about poor English)

My program gets all the names and boards, and when given a new number, it scan through every board and mark the number. Then it inspects whether players get bingo if necessary. I've tried to add as many break; as I can in order to reduce the times in loops, but it still ran for 1070ms.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,m;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    char players[n][64];    
    int board[n][m][m]; 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){            //input every player's name & board
        scanf("%s",&players[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<m;k++){
                scanf("%d",&board[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    int number;
    int foundx, foundy;
    int ifBreak = 0;
    int sum;
    int winNumber;
    int winCount = 0;
    int winners[n];
    for(int i=0;i<m*m && winCount==0;i++){
        scanf("%d",&number);            //input the numbers chosen to be marked         
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            ifBreak = 0;
            sum = 0;

            for(int k=0;k<m && ifBreak==0;k++){  //mark -1 on the number chosen
                for(int l=0;l<m;l++){
                    if(board[j][k][l] == number){
                        board[j][k][l] = -1;
                        foundx = k;
                        foundy = l;
                        ifBreak = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            ifBreak = 0;

            //inspect horizontal line
            for(int k=0;k<m && ifBreak==0 && i>=m-1;k++){  
                if(board[j][foundx][k] != -1)
                    break;
                sum += board[j][foundx][k];
            }
            if(sum == -m){  
                winNumber = number;
                winners[winCount] = j;
                winCount++;
                ifBreak = 1;                  
            }
            sum = 0;

            //inspect vertical line
            for(int k=0;k<m && ifBreak==0 && i>=m-1;k++){  
                if(board[j][k][foundy] != -1)
                    break;
                sum += board[j][k][foundy];
            }
            if(sum == -m){  
                winNumber = number;
                winners[winCount] = j;
                ifBreak = 1;                
                winCount++;
            }
            sum = 0;

            //inspect cross line
            for(int k=0;k<m && ifBreak==0 && i>=m-1 && foundx-foundy==0;k++){  
                if(board[j][k][k] != -1)
                    break;
                sum += board[j][k][k];
            }
            if(sum == -m && ifBreak==0){
                winNumber = number;
                winners[winCount] = j;
                winCount++;
                ifBreak = 1;        
            }
            sum = 0;

            //inspect cross line
            for(int k=0;k<m && ifBreak==0 && i>=m-1 && foundx+foundy==m-1;k++){ 
                if(board[j][k][m-1-k] != -1) 
                    break;
                sum += board[j][k][m-1-k];
            }
            if(sum == -m && ifBreak==0){
                winNumber = number;
                winners[winCount] = j;
                winCount++;
                ifBreak = 1;        
            }
            sum = 0;

        }
    }
    printf("%d",winNumber);

    for(int p=0;p<winCount;p++){
        printf(" %s",players[winners[p]]);
    }
}
```

I expect the program to run within a second when given the above two tests.

example input:2 3(num of players, side length of board, names, board, chosen numbers)
John
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
May
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 2 4 8 6 3 9 5 7
expected output:(the number when someone bingo,the names of players who won)
3 John May

Comment: Make sure that you iterate over the array in a way that is utilizing the cache, and the locality of the cache. Extract calculations out of loops.

Comment: Optimisation on code level (loop exits, cache use, ...) are usually not what gets you out of TLE. You will have to come up with a more efficient algorithm. Quite often, using math is the trick, but admittedly, that seems not to be the case here.

Comment: To help with helping, please explain more about what the program is supposed to do. What is the input definition? Give examples, with desired output accompanying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm, as is, offers quite some opportunities to optimise:

```
for(int k=0;k<m && ifBreak==0;k++)
{
    for(int l=0;l<m;l++)
    {
        if(...)
        {
            ifBreak = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code results in additional conditional branches in outer loop for every loop run. You can avoid this by using `goto`:

```
for(int k=0; k<m; k++)
{
    for(int l=0; l<m; l++)
    {
        if(...)
        {
            goto LoopExitN;
        }
    }
}
LoopExitN:
// next loop...
```

Then you have multiple loops, each running one after another – and each of having its own comparisons for stop conditions. If you combine all these loops into single loops, you spare many of these checks:

```
for(int k=0; k<m; k++)
{
    for(int l=0; l<m; l++)
    {
        // check for lines:       board[k][l]
        // check for columns:     board[l][k]
    }
    // check for first diagonal:  board[k][k]
    // check for second diagonal: board[k][m-k]
}
```

Solely, having an early exit condition gets more difficult; you might keep track for every row, column and the two diagonals if there was a failure, and if all these tracks get falsified, you'd exit. To get this more efficient, you'd have a total count of `2*m + 2` getting decremented every time you falsify one of the tracks – and exit the loop as soon as this count gets zero. If you really get faster with, you'd yet have to evaluate, though.

But now let's step back once again: Did you notice that with your algorithm, as is, you are re-evaluating every row, every column and every diagonal with every newly chosen number? That is pretty much of work to be done. And it is exactly here where you can safe most of the time: You should avoid these re-calculations! How? Pretty simple: Keep track of how many numbers are yet missing to complete the row/column/diagnoal:

```
for(int k=0; k<m; k++)
{
    for(int l=0; l<m; l++)
    {
        if(board[k][l] == number)
        {
            if
            (
                --rows[k] == 0 || --columns[l] == 0
                || (l == k && --diagnoal1 == 0)
                || (l == m - k - 1 && --diagnoal2 == 0)
            )
            {
                // we have a winner!
                goto CurrentPlayerCompleted;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you'd initialise all these rows/columns/diagonals with `m`...

*Edit:* As these modifications don't seem to be enough: Change the representation of your boards! Instead of having a `[m][m]` array (which effectively maps position to number), have a lookup table number to position!

This way you won't need the double loop inside (but you'll keep the rows/columns/diagonals fields from above!):

```
for(int i = 0; i < m * m && winCount == 0; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        // possibly need to check if the number is contained in board at all

        // possibly need to apply some hash function, for now, assuming
        // that an array for all numbers is sufficient, leaving the rest to you
        struct position pos = board[number];

        if
        (
            --rows[pos.row] == 0 || --columns[pos.column] == 0
            || (pos.column == pos.row && --diagonal1 == 0)
            || (pos.column == m - pos.row - 1 && --diagnoal2)
        )
        {
            // we have a winner!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  It  makes my program a little faster but isn't quite enough... now it's like 1030ms. Appreciate your suggestion though!!

Comment: @GalAbuser If switching to C++ is an option for you, then you get a ready to use hashmap with `std::unordered_map`. If not, you should consult your favourite search engine for a ready-to-use implementation in C, cannot recommend one, though, as never needed one in C.